# How can I use multiple HAVING or similar thing?

Tags: sql

I have some troubles where I want to show only teachers who is teaching 3 or more internal or external courses (not together). I guess my code now would be happy with 2 internal and 1 external etc. So how can I make sure it will actually count them individually and not together?

```
SELECT t.pnr, t.tname
FROM teacher t
JOIN teaches s ON t.pnr = s.pnr
JOIN course c ON s.coursecode = c.coursecode
WHERE c.coursetype = 'intern' OR c.coursetype = 'extern'
GROUP BY t.pnr, t.tname
HAVING COUNT(c.coursetype) > 2
```

Comment: Please give some sample data and your desired result?

Comment: Use a `UNION` for internal and external courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just count in where clause, instead of grouping:

```
SELECT t.pnr, t.tname
FROM teacher t
WHERE (select count(*) from teaches s               
         JOIN course c ON c.coursecode = s.coursecode
          and c.coursetype='intern'
        where t.pnr = s.pnr) > 2
        OR
      (select count(*) from teaches s               
         JOIN course c ON c.coursecode = s.coursecode
          and c.coursetype='extern'
        where t.pnr = s.pnr) > 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess this was exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use conditional aggregation to obtain counts of internal and external courses that the teacher teaches:

```
SELECT t.pnr, t.tname,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.coursetype = 'intern' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS intcourses,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.coursetype = 'extern' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS extcourses
FROM teacher t
JOIN teaches s ON t.pnr = s.pnr
JOIN course c ON s.coursecode = c.coursecode
GROUP BY t.pnr, t.tname
HAVING intcourses > 2 or extcourses > 2
```

Comment: @Jacob sorry I swapped two lines around and forgot to move the `,`. try my edit.

Comment: Now I get incorrect syntax near the keyword 'external', do you need to close the sum/case-thing before countinuing with FROM?

Comment: @Jacob sorry again - `external` is a reserved word in some flavours of SQL. Try the new version

Comment: *and forgot to move the ,* That's why commas should be at the beginning, not the end. Just saying... ;-)

Comment: Hehe no problem, it still says it wont let the column be named extern/intern in the end.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `having` makes sense.  You can do this as:

```
SELECT t.pnr, t.tname
FROM teacher t JOIN
     teaches s
     ON t.pnr = s.pnr JOIN
     course c
     ON s.coursecode = c.coursecode
WHERE c.coursetype IN ('intern', 'extern')
GROUP BY t.pnr, t.tname
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.coursetype = 'intern' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 3 OR
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.coursetype = 'extern' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 3 ;
```